# __builtin_frame_address - Attempt to access function stack frame fails

Tags: c++, g++, 32bit-64bit

Following (sample) code crashing when I compile/run on 64-bit, whereas it works fine on 32-bit Linux(Opensuse).
Ideally, when there is no more frame stack available or when the trace depth(here 10) is reached, the code should exit gracefully.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#define TRACE_DEPTH 10

void fourth()
{
        uintptr_t ebp_val;
        unsigned int i;
        unsigned long *ebp_ptr;
        ebp_val=reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(__builtin_frame_address(0));
        for(ebp_ptr=static_cast<unsigned long*>(reinterpret_cast<void*>(ebp_val)),i=0; i<TRACE_DEPTH ; i++)
        {
            printf("\n ebp_ptr=%"PRIxPTR"\n",ebp_ptr);
            if( (ebp_ptr=(unsigned long*)(*(ebp_ptr)))==0 )
            {
                printf("BREAK\n");
                break;
            }
        }
}
void third()
{
    fourth();
}

void second()
{
    third();
}

void first()
{
    second();
}

int main()
{
    first();
    return 0;
}
```

**Sample Output:**
 32-bit opensuse10.2 (g++ (GCC) 4.9.3)

```
ebp_ptr=bfca9aa8

ebp_ptr=bfca9ab8

ebp_ptr=bfca9ac8

ebp_ptr=bfca9ad8

ebp_ptr=bfca9ae8
BREAK
```

64-bit Opensuse 42.2 (g++ (GCC) 7.3.0)

```
ebp_ptr=7ffc1209cf10

ebp_ptr=7ffc1209cf20

ebp_ptr=7ffc1209cf30

ebp_ptr=7ffc1209cf40

ebp_ptr=7ffc1209cf50

ebp_ptr=4007b0

ebp_ptr=41d7894956415741
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: This is not `C`.

Comment: Updated tag to c++

Comment: You are assuming that the nested frame pointer will eventually be zero. Apparently that doesn't happen in 64-bit mode. I haven't seen any spec saying that it *should* happen.

Comment: Ok. Is there any way to tackle this on 64bit? May be some sentinel value or macro that can be used to mark the end of frame stack.